# imgkit gem not working on heroku in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imgkit

Hi I have a little application that is using imgkit to generate a png from some text. Every quote in my quote model uses imgkit to create a png version

app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format .html
      format.png do
        kit = IMGKit.new render_to_string, width: 1080, height: 1080
        send_data kit.to_png, type: "image/png", disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

It works well on my local machine but when i upload to heroku imgkit stops working.

I tried adding the binaries to the gem file as below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'imgkit'
gem 'wkhtmltoimage-binary'
gem 'devise'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Unfortunately this didn't work.

I then followed the instructions at https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit#heroku

and downloaded the 10.0 version mentioned from https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/obsolete-downloads/blob/master/README.md#linux

I added the file to bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 and I added the file config/initializers/imgkit.rb

with the following code to that file

```
IMGKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltoimage = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltoimage-amd64').to_s if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production'
end
```

I tested and found it didnt work and I keep getting the

`IMGKit::NoExecutableError (No wkhtmltoimage executable found at /app/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64`

can anyone point me in the right direction, please let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the binary at `app/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64`, but you're specifying `Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltoimage-amd64')`, which is `bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64`.

Either

- move the binary to `bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64`, or
- change `Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltoimage-amd64')` to `Rails.root.join('app', 'bin', 'wkhtmltoimage-amd64')`.

I'd recommend the first option as it is more typical to have binaries at the root in `bin/`.

Comment: hi @fphilipe thank you so much for the answer... good spotting... I really appreciate you taking the time

Comment: @JoeBloggs Does this implementation still work? I tried this but getting a blank white image.

Comment: @sunny its been ahile since i played with this app. why dont you explain your problem a little more, I sure its a typo somewhere and with some delving we can get to the bottom of it

Comment: @sunny did you find a solution?